# How to unmarshal json body to list of myclass in camel

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I'd like to know how to unmarshal JSON string body to List of MyClass. The following sample doesn't work well.

```
from("direct:testroute")
.log("Received body ${body}")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, List.class)
```

And I'd like to have something like (obviously doesn't work too)

```
from("direct:testroute")
.log("Received body ${body}")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, List<MyClass>.class)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create

```
JacksonDataFormat format = new ListJacksonDataFormat(MyClass.class);
```

and then:

```
//...
.unmarshal(format)
//...
```

[source](http://camel.apache.org/json.html)

Comment: There is also a useList option on the json data format, you can turn on

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you simply unmarshall as an array?

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyClass[].class)
```

I know it's not answer on how to unmarshall as a List but maybe someone can find it useful.